# How to add order items into a table using php and html

Tags: php, html

I want to create an order table but a little confused on how to add each it in its own row and column in the table.

```
function order_table_summary(){
        
    // Get and Loop Over Order Items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
       $name = $item->get_name();
       $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
       $item->get_total();
    }
    
    return '<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            // goes here
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <td>' . $order->get_line_total() . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO something like that. See the below code

```
function order_table_summary(){
 $html = '';   
// Get and Loop Over Order Items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    $html .= '<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>'.$item->get_name().'</td>
            <td>'.$item->get_quantity().'</td>
            <td>'.$item->get_total().'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
        <td>' . $order->get_line_total() . '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

}

    return $html;
        
}
```

cheers,

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```php
<?php

function order_table_summary(){
    
    $table_items = '';
    
    // Get and Loop Over Order Items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
       $name = $item->get_name();
       $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
       $price = $item->get_total();
       $table_items .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $name . '</td>
                <td>' . $quantity . '</td>
                <td>' . $price . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    
    return '
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            '. $table_items .'
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"></th>
                <td>' . $order->get_line_total() . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are everyting iterating whole table. That's why you are getting individual table. You should make one table and rest of the contents will be generated from inside loop. Please see the below answer and change it according to your requirements as well.

```
function order_table_summary() {

$table = '<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    ';

// Get and Loop Over Order Items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $name     = $item->get_name();
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
    $total    = $item->get_total();
    $table    .= '
        <tr>
        <td>' . $name . '</td>
        <td>' . $quantity . '</td>
        <td>' . $total . '</td>
        </tr>';
}
$table .='</table>';
return $table;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

You can do this like below as well:

```
function order_table_summary(){
    $table_items = '';
  
    // Get and Loop Over Order Items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
       $name = $item->get_name();
       $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
       $price = $item->get_total();

       $table_items .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $name . '</td>
                <td>' . $quantity . '</td>
                <td>' . $price . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }
    
    return '<table>
            <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            '.$table_items.' 
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2"></th>
            <td>' . $order->get_line_total() . '</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        ';
}
```